# Images are taking ages to load

Tags: javascript

I'm working a on a game critic website (personal project), I'm using the rawg game API to fetch the games, but loading the images from the API takes ages, I tried to reduce the number on images that I'm fetching (from 23 to 4), removing entire parts of my code (slider) to see if it changes something, changing the img to background img and trying the website on other computer (same speed), but sometimes the images load "instantly" even if when I clean the cache.

```
const sectionJeux = document.getElementById('jeux')

//show the 20 most popular games
function recupJeuPlusPopu(){
    fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2019-10-01,2020-04-07&ordering=-added')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        for(let i=0;i<=19;i++){
            let lienPage = document.createElement('a')
            lienPage.setAttribute('href',"index.php?id="+data.results[i].id + "&action=pageJeu")
            sectionJeux.appendChild(lienPage)

            //div with game info
            let newDiv = document.createElement("div")
            newDiv.setAttribute("class","container-game")
            lienPage.appendChild(newDiv)

            
            //adding game image
            let divImage = document.createElement("div")
            divImage.setAttribute("class","container-img-jeu")
            newDiv.appendChild(divImage)
            let image = document.createElement("img")
            image.setAttribute("class","img-jeu")
            image.src=data.results[i].background_image
            divImage.appendChild(image)
            

            //adding name
            let divText = document.createElement("div")
            divText.setAttribute("class","container-text-jeu")
            newDiv.appendChild(divText)
            let titreJeu = document.createElement("h2")
            titreJeu.setAttribute("class","titre-jeu")
            titreJeu.innerHTML=data.results[i].name
            divText.appendChild(titreJeu)

            //adding the platform
            let divPlateformeJeu = document.createElement("div")
            divPlateformeJeu.setAttribute("class","plateforme-jeu")
            divText.appendChild(divPlateformeJeu)
            let a = 0;
            while(data.results[i].platforms[a]){
                let plateform = document.createElement("img")
                plateform.setAttribute("class","plateform")
                plateform.src= chooseIcon(data.results[i].platforms[a].platform.name)
                divPlateformeJeu.appendChild(plateform)
                a++
            }
            let containerGenres = document.createElement("div")
            containerGenres.setAttribute("class","container-genres")
            newDiv.appendChild(containerGenres)

            //adding tags
            let b = 0;
            while(data.results[i].genres[b]){
                let genres = document.createElement("p")
                genres.setAttribute("class","genres")
                genres.innerHTML=data.results[i].genres[b].name
                containerGenres.appendChild(genres)
                b++
            }
            //release date 
            let dateDeSortie = document.createElement("p")
            dateDeSortie.setAttribute("class","releaseDate")
            newDiv.appendChild(dateDeSortie)
            dateDeSortie.innerHTML = "Released on: " + data.results[i].released
        }
    })
}
recupJeuPlusPopu()

//show plateform icons 
function chooseIcon(text){
    if(text == "PlayStation 4"){
        return('images/ps4.png')
    }
    else if(text == "PC"){
        return('images/windows.png')
    }
    else if(text == "Xbox One"){
        return('images/xbox.png')
    }
    else if(text == "Nintendo Switch"){
        return('images/switch.png')
    }
    else if(text == "macOS"){
        return('images/mac.png')
    }
    else if(text == "Linux"){
        return('images/linux.png')
    }
    else if(text == "iOS" || text == "Android"){
        return('images/smartphone.png')
    }
}
```

[image: image loading time (didnt finish for some images]

Comment: Well I took a look on some of your pics, they are Mega Bytes sized images, and that takes time to load besides they are a lot,
I think you should minimize the size of each, for example this image https://media.rawg.io/media/games/42f/42fe1abd4d7c11ca92d93a0fb0f8662b.jpg has `4320` width and `2160` height which you don't need, if you are just showing them in a gallery or something 600x400 is good, and saves you lot of loading time, **note** I saw that picture and others from your json file https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2019-10-01,2020-04-07&ordering=-added

Comment: 2.0 MB png 21 ms, 221kB jpg 37.86 s ... Cache the jpg images too.

Comment: @SaymoinSam How can i change the size of a image that i dont directly have on my computer ?

Comment: @Gobii I assume you have no server, you can download them to your local machine, resize them and then upload them to a free storage service and use the links from there for example https://cloudinary.com/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome support lazy loading, it may smooth the boost of loading 20 images at the same time.

```
   let image = document.createElement("img")
   image.setAttribute("class","img-jeu")
   image.setAttribute("loading","lazy")
   image.src=data.results[i].background_image
   divImage.appendChild(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it's not too late. You can crop the image in the actual URL after 'media/' like so:

https://media.rawg.io/media/crop/600/400/games/328/3283617cb7d75d67257fc58339188742.jpg

Now it'll be 600x400